# c++ 2D array non-regular grid interpolation

Tags: c++, interpolation

I got a non regular 2D array.

Here's some parts of the arrray, using "nearest neighbor" interpolation.

[image: nearest neighbor sample]
[image: Somewhere else on the grid...]

I would like to go from that :

[image: nearest neighbor interpolation]
to that :
[image: bicubic interpolation]

I can't use bicubic interpolation, because my grid is not regular.

What can I use ? (need to be fast - realtime render...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Delaunay triangulation of your irregular point cloud. Interpolate the color at every pixel across the triangle interior using the values in triangle vertices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation

Comment: That's probably overkill for the OP's problem, since their grid is quite close to being regular. But good in general.

Comment: I'm not sure it'll be compute-efficient

Comment: @user1219721: Triangulation is done once per cloud, then the rasterization is done once per pixel. I don't think you're gonna find something else.